# PyQt5 - Centre objects in QGridLayout

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, qgridlayout

I have a question. I have tried layouts in PyQt5 and it works partially. But not the way I want it.

This is my code:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

class CompanyLogin(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()

        self.layout = QGridLayout()

        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.setWindowTitle('Window')
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 1920, 1080)

        self.setupUI()

    def setupUI(self):
        company_note = QLabel(parent=self, text='Company: ')
        self.company = QComboBox(parent=self)
        self.company.addItem('t1')
        self.company.addItem('t2')

        password_note = QLabel(parent=self, text='Password: ')
        self.password = QLineEdit(parent=self)

        submit = QPushButton(parent=self, text='Submit')

        verticalSpacer = QSpacerItem(40, 20, QSizePolicy.Minimum, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.layout.addItem(verticalSpacer, 6, 0, Qt.AlignTop)

        self.layout.addWidget(company_note, 1, 0, Qt.AlignLeft)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.company, 1, 1, Qt.AlignRight)

        self.layout.addWidget(password_note, 2, 0, Qt.AlignLeft)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.password, 2, 1, Qt.AlignRight)

        self.layout.addWidget(submit, 3, 0, 1, 0, Qt.AlignCenter)
```

This is what my window looks like so far:

[image: Window Now]

And this is how I want it to look:

[image: Window After]

Comment: Are the current widgets the *only* widgets that will ever appear on that window, or are you going to add other objects to that layout?

Comment: Probably not. But why does that even matter?

Comment: Well, in layout management, *a lot* of things matter. For instance if you are going to add widgets that have expanding policies and insert them in a further, nested layout that you might want aligned or spaced differently.

Comment: Yeah, great, but how can I do what's in the picture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now the simplest solution *could* be to add this simple line:

```
self.layout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignTop|Qt.AlignHCenter)
```

But, actually, setting the layout alignment is often cause of unexpected problems, and the fact is that there are some issues in your code that should be fixed instead:

- you are adding widgets starting from the *second* row;
- you are using alignments when adding widgets, but that only ensures that the widget *minimum* size hint will be used, and the widget will *then* follow the alignment, which is clearly not what you need;
- a 0 value span as you did in the last line is wrong, since it indicates how many row or column cells a widget occupies (it's not index based), so it should be 1 or more;
- you should use [`setRowStretch()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgridlayout.html#setRowStretch) and [`setColumnStretch()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgridlayout.html#setColumnStretch);

<sup>Other small notes: [`layout()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#layout) is an *existing* dynamic function of all QWidgets, you shall not overwrite it; also, the `parent` argument in widget constructors is pointless if you then add the widget to the parent's layout; finally, use keyword arguments only when required.</sup>

```py
    def setupUI(self):
        self.layout.setColumnStretch(0, 1)
        self.layout.setColumnStretch(3, 1)
        self.layout.setRowStretch(3, 1)

        company_note = QLabel('Company: ')
        self.company = QComboBox()
        self.company.addItem('t1')
        self.company.addItem('t2')

        password_note = QLabel('Password: ')
        self.password = QLineEdit()

        submit = QPushButton('Submit')

        self.layout.addWidget(company_note, 0, 1)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.company, 0, 2)

        self.layout.addWidget(password_note, 1, 1)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.password, 1, 2)

        self.layout.addWidget(submit, 2, 1, 1, 2)
```